# How to check if the collection is selected in outliner?

Tags: python, scripting, collections

How to check if a collection is selected or not in the outliner using Python?

[image]

Here I've selected the following collections: "scene 1", "scene 2" and "scene 3".

Comment: very good question! there's no direct blender python api for that i guess. you can only know what the currently selected collection name is with `bpy.context.collection.name`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no direct way to check if certain collections are selected. You can only check what the name of the currently selected collection is using:

```
bpy.context.collection.name
```

and you can check what the actively selected collection is:

```
import bpy

for collection in bpy.data.collections:
    if collection == bpy.context.view_layer.active_layer_collection.collection:
        print(collection.name)
```

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299668/how-can-i-get-all-selected-collections-in-the-outliner/299669#299669